# Using HandlerAttribute in clients without referencing Unity but using own framework

Tags: c#, unity-container

We are building a framework that makes use of PolicyInjection to perform certain tasks. We make use of attributes for this. This code is written in a seperate framework solution.

Out CallHandler could look as follows:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyCallHandlerAttribute : HandlerAttribute
{
    ...
}
```

And in Unity we have:

```
namespace Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension
{
    public abstract class HandlerAttribute : Attribute
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the client solution we have a call handler (MyCallHandler) that we register using Unity. To execute the code in the call handler we need to add the attribute above the class/method/property of the model:

```
[MyCallHandler(params[])]
public class MyModel : IMyModel
{
    ...
}
```

The problem now is that to use MyCallHandler we need a reference to the PolicyInjection DLL for the compiler to understand that a HandlerAttribute is an Attribute. If there is no reference we get a *'MyCallHandler' is not an attribute class* warning (error when compiling).

**How can we implement this in such a way without needing to reference the Unity DLL in our client solution(s), but only our framework DLLs?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So after some research and finding similar, but much simpler examples, I've come to the conclusion that this is not feasible unless you include a large (if not all) the Unity code in your project.

What I did try is to create my own policy injection behavior that looks only for `MyCallHandler` attributes rather than any `HandlerAttribute`. This means that I can let `MyCallHandlerAttribute` implement `Attribute` instead of `HandlerAttribute`. So `MyModel` knows that `MyCallHandlerAttribute` is an attribute.

This worked like a charm, but the problem now was that `MyModel` has no idea what `ICallHandler` is. Again, this is a Unity defined interface. This is likely to continue for several other things (`IUnityContainer` and whatnot).

I can provide code examples of what I did if anyone is interested.